# C++ find first element in vector satisfying a condition using the std library

Tags: c++, search, vector, find

I have a vector containing objects, and each object has a method that returns a boolean.
I would like to find the first element whose method returns `true`.

I know I could simply iterate over the vector using a `for` loop, but **I'm looking for a solution that uses the std library**.

Googling I found nothing, just the `find` and `find_if` functions, but that's not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for a function that basically takes a reference to the vector and a lambda and returns the first element for which the lambda returns true.

Note: I would also be interested in a function that returns **an** element, and not necessarily the first.

Comment: That sounds pretty much like `find_if`.

Comment: The algorithms are defined in terms of iterators because that decouples the operation from the traversal of the container. If you pass `vec.begin()` and `vec.end()` you get the first element that matches, if you pass `vec.rbegin()` and `vec.rend()` you get the last element that matches. If you want to write a custom iterator that skips every other element, you can write that and still use the same `find_if`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`std::ranges::find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/find) and you'll use it like

```
auto iterator = std::ranges::find_if(vector, lambda);
```

This does require C++20 support.  If you don't have that, then use the plain old `std::find_if` like

```
auto iterator = std::find_if(vector.begin(), vector.end(), lambda);
```

Comment: How to I use the iterator? I need just one element

Comment: @ninazzo The iterator points to a single element.  To access it you just use `*iterator`, although before you do that you should check and make sure the iterator does not equal the end iterator of the vector.